# Earliest documented uses of the word "trap" for software interrupts?

Tags: etymology, computing

The etymology of the word "compiler" was discussed here a few years ago, [Etymology of "compiler" (computer term)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212566/etymology-of-compiler-computer-term), with very insightful and knowledgeable answers about the origin. So I thought I'd ask if anyone knows some of the earliest uses of the word "trap" for software interrupts.

## What research have I done myself?

The [IBM 704 manual from 1955](https://bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/704/24-6661-2_704_Manual_1955.pdf) is the oldest reference of the word "trap" that I have found. They have a "trapping mode" where they have "transfer traps", for debugging, where all branch instructions (both conditional and unconditional) transfer control to what is esentially the debugger. I.e., they have a "step into the next subroutine call" debug feature, and they are explicit with that "trapping mode" is specfically for that: *"the major use of the trapping mode is in program testing, where it permits observation of the flow of control"* (the 1955 manual, page 11). If the IBM 704 is actually one of the first uses of the word "trap" in computer architecture, then it is interesting, etymologically, that "traps" were originally a "trapping mode" that hijacked control at branch instructions, rather than  the "trap instructions" that it developed into. The difference is that it is not a "software trap" since there is no instruction for it in the software. It is an *external* "trap". The meaning, rhetorically, becomes a bit different. The processor actually "traps" the program from outside, literally, rather than the program "trapping itself" through an instruction, which is a rhetorically illogical concept.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146468/discussion-on-question-by-bipedaljoe-earliest-documented-uses-of-the-word-trap); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.